# how do i figure out the architecture of certain hardware?

Tags: compiling, binary, architecture

I have a tomtom one XL GPS. It is clearly a linux device: plugging it in shows a stripped down filesystem, and `strings gltt | less` (a program in the bin) shows:

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.2
__gmon_start__
gl_master
pkgGllStat
pkgLSbitLkup
g_GlSettings
GlDeallocateStorageSupl_cb
_apcIntegrLogMess
apcPwrModes
_ZN22TestStaticConstructors2x_E
testStaticCtor
_apcCalSrc
GetGlSettingsSupl_cb
SetSettingsSuplIsFromNVRAM_cb
bin2Hex
...
```

which tells me it was compiled for Linux. Let's say I want to compile some code for this device. I'm guessing it's not x86_64, but how could I find out which architecture it is? please note: I do not have a shell connection to the device yet.

Answer (score 2):

You might start with `file gltt`.

If that fails to tell anything useful, you might take a hex dump of the file with `od -t x1z -A x gltt | less` (there may be simpler commands for that available on your system, this is just what I'm used to using across a variety of systems), then see if the first 32 or so bytes can be interpreted as an [ELF file header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), and take a look at the architecture identifiers used.

Answer (score 0):

get arch info

```
uname -m
```

see uname --help

Comment: That would identify the architecture of the computer the GPS is plugged into, not of the GPS itself. Command line access to the GPS appliance is unlikely to be available.

Comment: if I knew how to use a usb cable to get into a shell on the tomtom, then that could work. that sounds like my next question.

Answer (score 0):

"arch" is the command which display the architecture of a machine.

For more details go through man page "man arch".

Comment: I dont have a shell on the machine yet.